# How to locate and replace values in dataframe based on some criteria

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to locate all places when in Col2 there is a change in value (for ex. change from A to C) and then modify value from Col1 (corresponding to row when the change happens, so when A -> C then it will be value in the same row as C) by dividing subtraction current value and previous value by two (in this example will be 1 + (1.5-1)/2 = 1.25.

Output table is result of replacing all that occurrences in whole table

How I can achieve that ?

| Col1 | Col2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 1.5 | C |
| 2.0 | A |
| 2.5 | A |
| 3.0 | D |
| 3.5 | D |

OUTPUT:

| Col1 | Col2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 1.25 | C |
| 1.75 | A |
| 2.5 | A |
| 2.75 | D |
| 3.5 | D |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `np.where` and series holding values of your formula

```
solution = df.Col1.shift() + ((df.Col1 - df.Col1.shift()) / 2)
df['Col1'] = np.where(~df.Col2.eq(df.Col2.shift()), solution.fillna(df.Col1), df.Col1)
```

Comment: It works as expected, but first value is always `nan`